# InputMismatchException in thread "main"

Tags: java, inputmismatchexception

First of all i am compete noob in Java. I tried to get the user input. Eclipse shows this error whenever i try to type double variable:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Scanner.nextDouble(Unknown Source)
at lesson1.MyClass.main(MyClass.java:10)
```

This is my code so far:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MyClass {

public static void main(String[] args) {
Scanner scan1 = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter some decimal value");
double userInput = scan1.nextDouble();
System.out.println("The entered value is ");
System.out.print(userInput);
}
```

Comment: There seems to be nothing noticably wrong with the code, it is likely that the scanner can not parse a double from your input. Try entering a number and then text and compare results

Comment: What exactly are you typing?

Comment: in console, write number value like 11.111 or something, if you write String then it will throw error like this.

Comment: try with 11,111

Answer (score 0):

Above codes are right!
You must ensure input decimal, such as 12.3
Below is my test：
[Test Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cYkY7.png)